# Wordpress Redirecting Non Category Pages /page/nnn to their Canonical URLs

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, canonical-link

I seemingly to have a strange issue I have found in almost every other Wordpress site.

Suppose, you have set your Blog home to a static WP page `/myhome`. And you have a separate page for blog `/blog`.

Now, this works fine and should be:

```
/blog
/blog/page/2
/blog/page/3
/blog/page/4
```

But, for all other pages, e.g. `/about-us`, these links also work:

```
/about-us/page/2
/about-us/page/3
/about-us/page/4
```

And show the content of the `/about-us` page.

My problem is that `/about-us/page/2` should ideally redirect to `/about-us` (it's canonical URL) since there are no paginations in any other page except the `/blog`.

What am I missing there ? This seems to happen on almost all sites I have checked and is really frustrating from SEO point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design and intentional. WordPress rewrites have become increasingly complex over the years, and many plugins utilise the `page` endpoint for a page (usually with a template and custom query) - redirecting introduces a potential world of pain.

Long story short, it doesn't matter anyway. WordPress adds [`<link rel="canonical />`](https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content) for pages, so no need to worry over duplicate content.

**Update:** For localised situations where you want to disregard the potential risks, this will canonicalize all page URLs - note that it does not check if a page is actually paginated (i.e. with the `<!--nextpage-->` quicktag) and will break this feature if you use it.

```
function wpse_199180_canonical_pages( $wp ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_page() && isset( $wp->query_vars['paged'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_queried_object() ), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_199180_canonical_pages' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the normal Worpdress behaviour, if pagination isn't enabled for a page it shouldn't accept the page argument. Just tested on a Wordpress page, `/mypage/page/2` gives a 404.

It probably have something to do with your theme and how the post are queried. For example. Look for `posts_per_page` and `numberposts` in your theme files, and locate the query that is related to your page. Change then the value to `-1` in order to disable the pagination.

One other solution would be redirect all paginated URLs (except for blog) - this goes in *functions.php*:

```
function redirect_pagination() {
    if(!preg_match('/blog/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        if(preg_match('/page\/[0-9]+\/?$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            $new_url = preg_replace('/(page\/[0-9]+\/?)$/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            wp_redirect($new_url, 301);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'redirect_pagination', 1 );
```

Comment: Didn't mentioned that you can go for a htaccess redirection too btw.

Comment: .htaccess will be tough and manual, since I can have some pages like `blog`, `news`, etc. where I want the pagination to work and not to work in all other cases. Then, I will always need to be on support for customer whenever a new such page is added.